# Generate report of single user based on id search

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am able to get the whole table data when i click on report but when i assign post to variable it is not generating single person report. I am not able to find what the error was.

**export.php**

```
  <?php 
      $host = "localhost"; // MySQL host name eg. localhost
      $user = "root"; // MySQL user. eg. root ( if your on localserver)
      $password = ""; // MySQL user password  (if password is not set for your root user then keep it empty )
      $database = "demo"; // MySQL Database name

      $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

      // Check connection
      if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
      }
      $id = $_POST['id']; // missing here
      $query ="SELECT id,attendants_name,task,stat, count(*)
      FROM allotted  WHERE id='$id'
      GROUP BY stat ";

      if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
      }
      $users = array();
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $users[] = $row;
        }
      }

      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Users.csv');
      $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
      fputcsv($output, array('Task Id', 'Name','Task','Status','No. of Tasks'));

      if (count($users) > 0) {
        foreach ($users as $row) {
          fputcsv($output, $row);
        }
      }
    ?>
```

**report.php**

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='Export()' style='color:#fff;' class='btn btn-task bt1'> Report </a> ";
function Export() {
  var conf = confirm("Export users to CSV?");
  if(conf == true) {
    window.open("export.php", '_blank');
  }
}
```

The code for report is mentioned above. I want to get the report of single user with value fetched from database. I don't want to give something like id = '1' in query. I want value to come dynamically when search id of the person.

Comment: missing single quote here $id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Thanks for the edit. But in the code i checked it and it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching $id from a post request, but I don't see you are sending the post request. Attach id with URL and send to export.php and fetch it using $_GET. 
See below example

**report.php**

```
// attach id with onlick function like below (dynamically)
echo "<a href='#' onclick='Export(id)' style='color:#fff;' class='btn btn-task bt1'> Report </a> ";

function Export(id) {
  var conf = confirm("Export users to CSV?");
  if(conf == true) {
    window.open("export.php?id=" + id, '_blank'); //attach the id with URL (GET method)
  }
}
```

**export.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; // MySQL host name eg. localhost
$user = "root"; // MySQL user. eg. root ( if your on localserver)
$password = ""; // MySQL user password  (if password is not set for your 
root user then keep it empty )
$database = "demo"; // MySQL Database name

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if ($con->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
$id = $_GET['id']; // retrieve URL binded id from $_GET method
$query ="SELECT id,attendants_name,task,stat, count(*)
FROM allotted  WHERE id='$id'
GROUP BY stat ";

if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
  exit(mysqli_error($con));
}
$users = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $users[] = $row;
  }
}

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Users.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Task Id', 'Name','Task','Status','No. of Tasks'));

if (count($users) > 0) {
  foreach ($users as $row) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173822/discussion-between-rumesh-and-praveen-kumar-l).